# A curious way of passing a parameter to a method

Tags: java, generics, parameters

I was going through the [Exchange Web Services Java API](https://github.com/buckett/ews-java) code and saw a design choice in the way the developers passed arguments to their methods. May you can help explain the benefits of the technique --

The type that is to be processed by the method is wrapped by a Generic Wrapper class before being passed into the method, for example if the method is to work on a String, new Param() is passed into the method where Param is defined as follows

```
class Param<T> {
  private T param; 
  public T getParam() { return param; }
  public void setParam(T param) { this.param = param }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the source -- The method works on an HttpWebRequest object.
The caller creates an instance of the Param, i.e. bounded by the HttpWebRequest class. Then that instance is passed into the method, as you can see in the method signature  --

```
protected HttpWebRequest emit(OutParam<HttpWebRequest> request) 
throws Exception {
   request.setParam(this.getService().prepareHttpWebRequest()); 
   OutputStream urlOutStream = request.getParam().getOutputStream();
   EwsServiceXmlWriter writer = new EwsServiceXmlWriter(this.service,urlOutStream);
   this.writeToXml(writer);
   urlOutStream.flush();
   urlOutStream.close();
   writer.dispose();

   request.getParam().executeRequest();
   if(request.getParam().getResponseCode() >= 400)
   {
      throw new Exception("The remote server returned an error:("+request.getParam().getResponseCode()+")"+request.getParam().getResponseText());
    }
    return request.getParam();
}
```

Then why not just pass the HttpWebRequest object --
The developers use this pattern repeatedly all over the code base which makes me think there is some good reason for it. But I just can't see the benefit... please enlighten.

Comment: Can you point to one such instance in github, please? thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the method entrance, the wrapped HttpWebRequest instance is expected to be null. This is a way to return the instance by an other mean than the return statement, even if something goes wrong during the method call (if an exception is thrown for instance). This pattern is somehow equivalent to the keyword `out` in C#. It could be also used to return an object + an error status :

```
bool getGreetings(OutParam<Greetings> greetings) {
  if (aCondition) {
     greetings.setParam(new Greetings("Hello");
     return true; // everything's fine
   }
   return false;
}
```

rather than writing :

```
Greetings getGreetings() {
  if (aCondition) {
     return new Greetings("Hello");
  }
  return null; // caller will have to test a null condition to know it the operation was ok
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, it's passing a container, which can be modified.

Comment: It helps to define the type that can be stored, like in a collection.

Comment: You could do it without a generic wrapper indeed, but in that case you would have to create a dedicated container for each object on which you want to use such a pattern... Unless you replace 'T' by 'Object', but it would far less safe and readable.

Comment: So, in your opinion @Yanflea and others, is this a good pattern? It looks to me like a healthy  use of `finally` clauses would solve the issue in a cleaner way.

Comment: I couldn't say if it is bad or good... Maybe some people have a stronger opinion than me on this subject... Personnally, I often use out/ref keywords in C#, because it is part of the language, and it is handy in some occasions. But I almost never use this pattern in Java, because it's true that you actually can do without it, and since in java there is no dedicated keyword for it. Using a Container object to address the lack of a real 'out' keyword is a nice trick though.

Comment: @Yanflea, for the method, getGreetings, in java u can pass the parameter and return something else -- 
`boolean getGreetings(Greetings greetings){... do something with greetings -- and return boolean... }` but as you noted, where the creation of the object is the KEY! in this example i put, the creation happens before method is called. In the question example the creation is in the callee